# SQL Server 2016 R Statistics: can't find function

Tags: sql-server-2016, r

I'm trying to get R Statistics running on my Dev server. I'm using [this microsoft tutorial](https://microsoft.github.io/sql-ml-tutorials/R/rentalprediction/step/3.html).

I have the default installation of R Analytics as provided my the SQL Server installation:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL\Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\R_SERVICES\

And I also have the Microsoft R Client 3.4.3 which contains the RX functions installed to:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Client

We have a Tutorial database, with test data, R is enabled and I can do "hello world". Everything works up until Step 3.3 Code Step 3.

```
> --Save Linear model to table 
> DECLARE @model VARBINARY(MAX); EXEC generate_rental_R_native_model "linear", @model OUTPUT; INSERT INTO
> rental_models (model_name, native_model, lang) VALUES('linear_model',
> @model, 'R');
```

When I run it I get the following error:

> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 59 A 'R' script error occurred
>   during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT
>   0x80004004. Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 59 An external script
>   error occurred:  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    could not
>   find function "rxSerializeModel" Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval
>   -> eval
>
> Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information. Error in
>   eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for
>   more information. Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->
>   .Call Execution halted

I'm on SQL 2016 SP2 CU3, so I know I don't have the predict() function but everything up until that point should work.

If I run RGUI I can prove that rxSerializeModel is there. This works:

```
myIris <- iris
myIris[1:5,]
form <- Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species
irisLinMod <- rxLinMod(form, data = myIris)
serializedModel <- rxSerializeModel(irisLinMod)
```

However if I run this fromSQL, I just get an error.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/revoscaler/rxsqllibpaths
```

> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 10 A 'R' script error occurred
>   during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT
>   0x80004004. Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 An external script
>   error occurred:  Error in path.expand(new) : could not find function
>   "rxSqlLibPaths" Calls: source ... .libPaths -> Sys.glob -> path.expand
>   -> path.expand
>
> Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information. Error in
>   eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for
>   more information. Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->
>   .Call Execution halted

Why can't SQL see it? Is it a path issue? How do I know where SQL is looking for libraries?

Comment: Make sure your service account for the SQL Server Launchpad service has access to that `demoScripts` directory.

Comment: @AMtwo I added permissions for launchpad on both C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Open & C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Client and got the same error.

Comment: I get the feeling that SQL is using the wrong instance of the libraries. How do I check or prove where SQL is looking when it's trygin to execute R code?